# Android Sqlite After Adding Column Select entries base on conditions

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, null, alter-table

So this happened when I tried to mark deleted entries to have a 'deleted' value of '1' instead of deleting it.

I added a column to a database in my app using `ALTER TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ADD COLUMN "+NEW_COLUMN_NAME+" "+type+";");` and made other appropriate changes in the database provider (when insert 0 is inserted), however, something weird happened.

After adding it, the following things happen:

1. `SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME` - Returns all rows (as expected)
2. `SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE NEW_COLUMN_NAME=1` returns rows with NEW_COLUMN_NAME=1 (as expected).
   However,
3. `SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE NEW_COLUMN_NAME=0` returns newly inserted rows (as expected).
4. `SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE NEW_COLUMN_NAME!=1` returns ONLY newly inserted rows (not the old rows)
5. `SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE NEW_COLUMN_NAME=null` returns nothing.

does Android not comply with http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html or did I miss something?

ran in Android 2.2 emulator.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE NEW_COLUMN_NAME = null
```

Will return an empty row set in pretty much any datebase because in SQL, the expression `NULL = x` is false for all `x` (even an `x` of NULL). Try this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE NEW_COLUMN_NAME IS NULL
```

Similar NULL issues will apply to this one:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE NEW_COLUMN_NAME != 1
```

so try:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE NEW_COLUMN_NAME != 1 OR NEW_COLUMN_NAME IS NULL
```

instead.

This isn't anything specific to SQLite or Android, this is just normal SQL behavior. If you don't absolutely need to allow NULL values in your columns, create them with `NOT NULL` (and possibly a default value) to avoid some confusion and frustration.